# Which properties of a metal can be measured via an Inductor in an $RLC$ circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, conductors, inductance, metals

I am trying to understand the properties of metals by using them as cores for an inductor in an $RLC$ circuit. Now the resistivity, saturation point, magnetic permeability electric permittivity all should affect the response of the AC circuit. Now I can estimate the magnetic permeabilty by measuring the inductance but how do I measure any other properties? It will also be very helpful if anybody can suggest any other property that I can measure that I might have not included.

Comment: Resistivity is not obvious. I miss hysteresis.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.